# How to load CSS files based on Session Storage values dynamically in React

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, dynamic, loading

At present, we are having no conditions to load CSS files. So, we are importing the required .scss files statically in styles.scss file that we have. But now, we have to load different scss files(themes) in the same styles.scss file based on the data we get in session storage. Can someone help me how to do it?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't really understand your question. You need to import *what* files from `styles.scss`? What does that data from `sessionStorage` which is supposed to act as the condition look like?

Answer (score 1):

You will not be able to directly load .scss files into browsers. It needs to be transpiled into .css files at runtime as .scss files are used strictly for development convenience.

You also won't be able to **conditionally import .scss file within another .scss file** depending on `sessionStorage` value stored in the browser.

However, you can **conditionally import different style (.css) files** depending on `sessionStorage` values. Take at look at below example.

```js
const LightTheme = React.lazy(() => import('./themes/lightTheme'));
const DarkTheme = React.lazy(() => import('./themes/darkTheme'));

const ThemeSelector = ({ children }) => {
  const CHOSEN_THEME = sessionStorage.getItem('TYPE_OF_THEME') || TYPE_OF_THEME.DEFAULT;
  return (
    <>
      <React.Suspense fallback={<></>}>
        {(CHOSEN_THEME === TYPE_OF_THEME.LIGHT_MODE) && <LightTheme />}
        {(CHOSEN_THEME === TYPE_OF_THEME.DARK_MODE) && <DarkTheme />}
      </React.Suspense>
      {children}
    </>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create separate SCSS files for each theme you want to use.

In your JavaScript code, check the session storage for the current theme data.

Based on the theme data in session storage, dynamically update the href attribute of the link element that references the styles.scss file to point to the appropriate theme SCSS file.